# Antivirus for virtual Server 2012 R2 without additional installation requirements

Tags: windows, antivirus

Looking for antivirus to run on virtualized Server 2012 R2 but trying to establish which do not have additional install requirements & overhead.

We had decided on GFI:Vipre but have now discovered that it requires .Net 3.5 installed which Windows Server 2012 R2 does not have by default. Allowing that to be installed is just going to increase the MS Updates workload.

Any suggestions for a clean Antivirus product which does not require .Net 3.5 to be installed?

All we want is something to protect a single virtualised win 2012 R2 domain controller and file server.  Nothing particularly clever just a few applications and a bunch of file/print serving being done.  Not worried about the client workstations, server-side only.
Also preferably something which does not have any other install requirements like .Net 3.5.

Comment: So, you want a resident antivirus, that is standalone and can be managed how?

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.